# Modify mongodb ID policy

Tags: c++, mongodb

I'm writing a system with registration. And by device capabilities the requirement is to have 16 bytes for user id. Also, I know that mongo creates the ObjectID for each object inserted, which is unique at least in the collection. And this id is 12 bytes long. I was wondering - is it possible to change config somewhere in mongo to make it generate 16 bytes id? I thought about padding 12 bytes ids with 4 zero bytes, it is a solution, but it's brute force imo. Is there a better way?

Comment: First you can change your application to insert these IDs but then you could also create a .mongorc for the console which will replace the objectId helper with your own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no server side configuration to change the format of ObjectIDs, but you can provide whatever `_id` you want yourself within your application.  For inserts, drivers generate the `_id` for you locally anyway behind the scenes on insert; the server only generates it for `upsert` operations.

As long as you don't depend on `upsert`, the best thing to do is to generate your own `_id` fields.  For 16-bytes, you could use a UUID generator, for instance.

Comment: could you please show the example how I can insert the `_id` in mongo? I thought the `_*` fields are reserved for internal mongodb usage only. Or I should follow the standard insertion procedure with field `_id` specified?

Comment: You can add _id like any other field.